# Running PCA on cointegrated variables

Tags: time-series, pca, covariance, cointegration, finance

I know that there are a lot of questions about the topic but I would like some extra explanation.

What is the effect of running PCA on cointegrated variables?

I'm doing PCA on financial data trough eigendecomposition of a covariance matrix of returns.

For sure, I think the first factor will explain a large share of the variance. But what about the other factors?

Thank you

Comment: While running a PCA on prices (which may be cointegrated) could make the question of cointegration relevant, returns are likely I(0) and hence not cointegrated.

Comment: Thank you Richard. Yes, I agree. but to find out if there's a factor structure, I should run a PCA on the covariance matrix of (let's say only correlated, for the moment) returns - right?

Comment: The latter question is a financial, not a statistical one. I do not know the answer. But let me try: if you are looking for a factor structure within prices, consider doing PCA on prices (where you encounter cointegration); if within returns, do PCA on returns.